# How to efficiently edit strings after dot in vim

Tags: vim, editor

In vim, I have to change `someText.someTextAfterDot` string to `someText.somethingDifferent`. The cursor is at the `t` in `After`. What should be the most efficient way to do this?

- If I use 'cw' command then that removes the complete `someText.someTextAfterDot` including `someText` which I don't think is efficient because now I have to type the `someText` again.
- Normally, I use 'F.ce' (find the last . and edit till end of current word) command and then type `somethingDifferent`. This seems like a lot of work as in other editors (like WebStorm or Sublime) a simple double click on `someTextAfterDot` can do the trick.

Is there any other more efficient way to do this in vim?

Comment: First of all `cw` should only go forward so only remove `terDot`. Now if you use `ciw` and `'iskeyword'` includes a dot then your problem lies with the `'iskeyword'` setting. Find out the last place `'iskeyword'` is set by doing the following: `:verbose set iskeyword?`

Comment: @PeterRincker has the correct answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `cw` should only go forward so only remove `terDot`. If `cw` is doing anything more then I assume you have some bad mappings.

The "inner" word text object, `iw`, is what you need. e.g. `ciw`. However if you have added `.` to `'iskeyword'` then word's will include `.` and the behavior of `ciw` will be incorrect.

To find out where `'iskeyword'` is last set use the following command:

```
:verbose set iskeyword?
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'iskeyword'
:h iw
:h w
:h cw
:h :verbose
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! This helped. And yes! my mistake, I meant be `ciw` not `cw`

Answer (score 0):

My intuition would be to type `bdeisomethingDifferent`.  I dunno that it's a great improvement, but it at least doesn't make you type the `.` again the way `F.ce` does.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use *change inner word* for that. You simply have to type

`ciwsomethingDifferent`

Check the documentation for [text object selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects) too.